# Fire a GTM tag once per user

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm just starting to integrate GA4 and GTM to my website for the first time ever and I have an issue with one thing:

I need a tag to fire once per user. However, the only available options are as follows:
[image]

Is there a way to do that without any engineering help and data layers? Basically this tag would fire on the first ever page visit.

I have tried to search for HTML custom variables, but was able to find the variable "per session", however, I need a tag to fire "per user".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it in GTM.

In GTM, on the initial hit, you run a custom html code that checks whether the user has a cookie that you will set later. If it doesn't have the cookie, you fire your one-per-user event and set the cookie. If it does have the cookie, you update the cookie to prolong its expiration.

It has little value though and running code on every pageview just to fire one event once per user sounds a little bit excessive. You probably want to do this because you're not familiar with a chunk of functionality that solves your problem. Sounds like a mistake to me.